# Interactive Service Server

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For actions, there is the very convenient `axserver.py` node in the actionlib package that provides a simply GUI for an interactive action server.

Is there something similar for services as well? I may implement something myself but would like to avoid unnecessary work if there is already something working out there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291324/interactive-service-server/) by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 382 on 2018-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
Would the [rqt_service_caller](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_service_caller) suffice?

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2018-05-16**:
I did not test, but from the description it is for calling services, i.e. it is a GUI for the client. What I want is a GUI for the server. However, I just managed to adapt the `axserver.py` for services, it was actually easier than I expected.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
Yes, the rqt plugin is a service client. I'd missed the bit where `axserver.py` is a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since I did not find an existing solution, I took the `axserver.py` and modified it to work with services instead.
It is available here: https://github.com/synapticon/rx_service_tools

---

Originally posted by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) with karma: 382 on 2018-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0